# Counting results from multiple tables with same column

Tags: mysql, count

I have a system where, essentially, users are able to put in 3 different pieces of information: a tip, a comment, and a vote.  These pieces of information are saved to 3 different tables.  The linking column of each table is the user ID.  I want to do a query to determine if the user has any pieces of information at all, of any of the three types.  I'm trying to do it in a single query, but it's coming out totally wrong.  Here's what I'm working with now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  *
  FROM tips T
  LEFT JOIN comments C ON T.user_id = C.user_id
  LEFT JOIN votes V ON T.user_id = V.user_id
  WHERE T.user_id = 1
```

This seems to only be getting the tips, duplicated for as many votes or comments there are, even if the votes or comments weren't made by the specified user_id.

I only need a single number in return, not individual counts of each type.  I basically want a sum of the number of tips, comments, and votes saved under that user_id, but I don't want to do three queries.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**: Actually, I don't even technically need an actual count, I just need to know if there are any rows in any of those three tables with that user_id.

**Edit 2:** I almost have it with this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT T.tip_id),
  COUNT(DISTINCT C.tip_id),
  COUNT(DISTINCT V.tip_id)
  FROM tips T
    LEFT JOIN comments C ON T.user_id = C.user_id
    LEFT JOIN votes V ON T.user_id = V.user_id
  WHERE T.user_id = 1
```

I'm testing with user_id 1 (me).  I've made 11 tips, voted 4 times, and made no comments.  My return is a row with 3 columns: 11, 0, 4.  That's the proper count.  However, I tested it with a user that hasn't made any tips or comments, but has voted 3 times, that returned 0 for all counts, it should have returned: 0, 0, 3.

The problem that I'm having seems to be that if the table that I'm using for the WHERE clause doesn't have any rows from that user_id, then I get 0 across the board, even if the other tables DO have rows with that user_id.  I could use this query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tips WHERE user_id = 2) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE user_id = 2) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE user_id = 2) AS total
```

But I really wanted to avoid running multiple queries, even if they're subqueries like this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to ace, I figured this out:

```
SELECT
  (COUNT(DISTINCT T.tip_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT C.tip_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT V.tip_id)) AS total
  FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN tips T ON U.user_id = T.user_id
    LEFT JOIN votes V ON U.user_id = V.user_id
    LEFT JOIN comments C ON U.user_id = C.user_id
  WHERE U.user_id = 4
```

the users table contains the actual information bout the user including, obviously, the user id.  I used the user table as the parent, since I could be 100% sure that the user would be present in that table, even if they weren't in the other tables.  I got the proper count that I wanted with this query!

Comment: I'm not sure that your database design makes sense. Maybe it does but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  Users post a tip on a challenge.  That tip gets sent to the "tips" table and contains, among other things, the user_id of the poster.  Other users can comment on that tip, those get sent to the "comments" table and also contains the user_id.  Finally, users can vote on the tips, they get saved in the "votes" table and also contain the user_id.  This is the only way to do it and be able to keep track of who posts/does what.  I need to determine if a user has voted, or posted a tip or comment, so that I can allow or disallow them changing their display name.

Comment: The reason why you get the 0,0,0 instead of 0,0,3 is that your base table is `tips` which doesn't have a user_id then you `LEFT JOIN` it with `votes` with a user_id. At first all rows will be get from `tips` and then if you `LEFT JOIN` it with other table. MySql will look for every user_id that have in `votes` then join it. Then all the user_id that don't have in `LEFT table or tips` will be exclude to get from `votes` that's why you will not get that user_id in `votes`. Also you will have a problem using DISTINCT that way because the result of every equal value in a column will be count as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question. You want to count the total comments + tips + votes for each user. Though is not really clear to me take a look at below query. I added columns for details this is a cross tabs query as someone teach me.

**EDITED QUERY:**

```
  SELECT
         COALESCE(COALESCE(t2.tips,0) + COALESCE(c2.comments,0) + COALESCE(v2.votes,0)) AS `Totals`
    FROM parent p
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.user_id, COUNT(t.tip_id) AS tips FROM tips t GROUP BY t.user_id) t2
      ON p.user_id = t2.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT c.user_id, COUNT(c.tip_id) AS comments FROM comments c GROUP BY c.user_id) c2
      ON p.user_id = c2.user_id               
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.user_id, COUNT(v.tip_id) AS votes FROM votes v GROUP BY v.user_id) v2
      ON p.user_id = v2.user_id
   WHERE p.user_id = 1;
```

Note: This used a parent table in order to get the result of a table which doesn't in other table.

The reason why I use a sub-query in my JOIN is to create a virtual table that will get the sum of tip_id for each table. Also I'm having problem with the `DISTINCT` using the same query of yours, so I end up with this query.

I know you prefer not using sub-queries, but I failed without a sub-query. For now this is all I can.

Comment: I just need to know if the user has voted or posted a tip or comment.  If any of those are true then the count should be greater than 0.  Check the edit in the first post.  There are two columns that are the same in all three tables: user_id and tip_id, since the comments and votes are linked to the tip itself.  Basically if any of the three tables contains a row where user_id = #, then I should get a number greater than 0, if none of the tables contains a row where user_id = #, then the count should be 0.

Comment: I think the query will show the result you want. I'm going to edit field name in the query to reflect with your fields and I will add the WHERE Clause for ID. If it still not what you looking for, I'll try to make a new query if I have a time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your query at all.  What is the purpose of the select in the FROM clause?  You're selecting rows into a clause that wants a table.  I get all sorts of errors when I try to run it.  I only need a single number in return.  That number will be the sum of the number of tips, comments, and votes made by a specified user_id.  If the user has made 1 tip, no comments, and 2 votes, then the count will be 3.  If they've made 5 tips, 2 comments, and no votes then the count will be 7, make sense?

Comment: I guess the error cause by having different field name use in my query against yours. As I read your updated question that your having a problem if the user_id does not contain in the table of your where clause. As I understand the use of joining the table, results of 0 will be my expected answer even though you have that user_id in some of the table. To solve this you must have a parent table which will be your base table and will use in your `WHERE` clause. You also don't want to use a sub query so my query is in appropriate. For now try to add a parent/user table.

Comment: Good for you, I hope you not get in trouble with the DISTINCT. If you have same user_id and same tip_id in a table the would be count as 1. Your total will not be as you expected. Anyway you only want to know if the user either have a tips,comments and votes then your OK with what you have.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The user_id and tip_id are different things.  tip_id doesn't exist in the user table, only tips, comments, and votes.  Each tip_id is distinct in the tips table, but in the votes and comments table there can be multiple instances of the same tip_id.  Users cannot vote on a tip more than once and if they comment twice the count will be 1, which will still be enough for me to tell that they've commented.